# How to access tomcat manager user interface?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using spring tcserver-2.9.5 (tomcat) as webserver. I want to access tomcat manager UI. I tried to access it
by navigating to `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` but I get a blank page.

I have added the below entry to my tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="myadmin" password="adminPassword" roles="manager"/>
```

What I am missing here? Is 8080 not the right port for the tomcat manager UI?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `local` instead of `localhost`. Is that a typo?

Navigate to the base url for Tomcat `http://localhost:8080`. If Tomcat is running on that port, and there are no webapps running at `/`, Tomcat will bring up its own home page.

Click on the Manager App button on that page to navigate to the Management Console. Note the URL for future use.

Comment: https://localhost:8443 displays blank page but i can access application with https://localhost:8443/myApplication ?

Comment: right.. just try http://localhost:8080. Does it show a green Tomcat screen? There is a big [Manager] button on the right.

Comment: it displays blank page

Comment: actually i do not see any manager application under C:\tcserver-2.9.5\webapps